# Number of irreducible component of the generic fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a surjective, finite morphism between projective varieties i.e., $X, Y$ irreducible. Is the genric fiber $X_\eta$ of $f$ also irreducible?

Comment: The generic fiber is irreducible, but not geometrically irreducible.